# How do I set the figsize and dpi in matplotlib so that the image has the required size and quality?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing, latex

I need to combine the images into one. I would like the resulting image to consist of 7 rows and 9 columns. Each component image has dimensions of 256 x 256. I would like these images not to be resized, that is, I would like the resulting image to have dimensions of at least 9 * 256 x 7 * 256 = 2304 x 1792. The easiest way for me to do this would be using numpy and concatenating the images together using, for example, np.concatenate. However, I decided to use matplotlib, because it is much easier to add labels to the axes with it.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble setting the right figsize and dpi values.

I've found that a good way is to set the dpi parameter to 100, and for example the height as the height in pixels divided by the dpi value. As below.

```
cols = 9
rows = 7

img_size = (256, 256)
dpi = 100

fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(img_size[0] * cols // dpi, img_size[1] * rows // dpi), dpi=dpi)
```

1. Unfortunately, when I save this image, its dimensions are 2359 x 1720.
2. My second problem is that despite setting wspace=0 and hspace=0, there are gaps between the subplots.

```
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0, left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1)
```

[image]

3. In addition, I do not know what is the best format in which I should save this image, so that the text is in good quality and so that the quality of the image does not degrade significantly when zooming (I will be using this image in Latex).

Below I attach a simple example for reproduction.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = 9
rows = 7

img_size = (256, 256)
dpi = 100

fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(img_size[0] * cols // dpi, img_size[1] * rows // dpi), dpi=dpi)

for row_idx, row in enumerate(axes):
    images = [Image.new('RGB', (256, 256), color='grey') for i in range(cols)]
    
    for col_idx, (col, image) in enumerate(zip(row, images)):
        col.imshow(image)
        
        col.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        col.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        col.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
        col.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        col.set_xticks([])
        col.set_yticks([])

        if col_idx == 0:
            col.set_ylabel('name', fontsize=30)
            

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0, left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1)
plt.savefig('example.png', bbox_inches='tight', format='png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you need each of your pixels to come through unchanged, using a rendering library is not the way to go. matplotlib is for creating plots, not for manipulating images. Unless you output in a vector format, images will change. And in a vector format you’re not creating a composite image, you’re creating a document that contains your original images. There are many ways to add text on top of an image, I would research those instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. I do not get why you would need specific dimensions. Depending on the scaling of the image in your final document the dimensions will become irrelevant.
2. Unfortunately I do not have a direct solution for these gaps, but since I was wondering why not combining the images in numpy and then using matplotlib for the labelling, I played around a bit based on your code (by the way, thanks for the very nice example code!):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = 9
rows = 7

img_size = (256, 256)
dpi = 500
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13, 9), dpi=dpi)

# generating a single image 
idx = 0
image = np.array([])
for row_idx in range(rows):
    colors = ['grey', 'blue']  # used to crate a chessboard pattern, which was better for visual feedback

    images = [Image.new('RGB', (256, 256), color=colors[(row_idx + i) % 2]) for i in range(cols)]
    row_image = np.concatenate(images, axis=1)
    if row_idx == 0:
        image = row_image
    else:
        image = np.concatenate((image, row_image))

plt.imshow(image, origin="lower")
axes = plt.gca()
axes.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axes.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
axes.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
axes.set_xticks([])

axes.set_yticks([128 + idx * 256 for idx in range(rows)])
axes.set_yticklabels(["Name" for _ in range(rows)], rotation=90, fontsize=30, va="center")  # va="center" centers the label nicely

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0, left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1)

plt.savefig('example1.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', format='pdf') 
plt.savefig('example1.png', bbox_inches='tight', format='png')  
plt.show()
```

3. To avoid difficulties in readability due to resolution issues a vector format is best. I am not sure whether LaTeX can handle .svg. Therefore I tried a .pdf export which works nicely. Also, if you use a dpi of 500 also in a .png the labels are nicely readable, even for very large zooming (beyond something useful for a LaTeX document). Therefore I would suggest to go for one of these options.